# Returning the value as the first field in an influxdb query?

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to return just a value, and not a time from influxdb?

I know influxdb is a Time Series Database, so it includes the time regardless, but the tool I'm using requires the first field displayed from the query to be a value, and not a time.

I've also tried switching the order of the arguments and time is still the first argument returned in the query.

```
select value,time FROM smart_threshold WHERE host =~ /proxmox/ AND instance = 'sda' AND type_instance='reallocated-sector-count'  limit 1
```

Result:

```
name: smart_threshold
time                value
----                -----
1512183206033040777 36
```

Would it be possible to return:

```
name: smart_threshold
value               time
------              ----
36                  1512183206033040777
```

or just:

```
name: smart_threshold
value
------
36
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it seems there's no other way than do simple man-in-the-middle script that would swap two values in the output (in case you don't own "the tool").

What the tool is that, though?

Comment: Well, grafana uses data sources, and it connects directly to them as far as I know, so yeah what tool indeed?  I guess one could start by using something like `netcat` to see if it could be connected to and proxied through that way.